# tidyr::uncount() error within custom function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

What stupid thing am I doing here when using `tidyr::uncount` in a function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(a = c(2, 3, 4),
                   freq = c(3, 4, 5))
df
#   a freq
# 1 2    3
# 2 3    4
# 3 4    5
#WORKS
df2 <- df %>% 
    tidyr::uncount(freq)
df2
#     a
# 1   2
# 1.1 2
# 1.2 2
# 2   3
# 2.1 3
# 2.2 3
# 2.3 3
# 3   4
# 3.1 4
# 3.2 4
# 3.3 4
# 3.4 4
```

But when I put it into a function I am getting an error `Error: weights must evaluate to a numeric vector Called from: tidyr::uncount(., frequency_var)`.

```
my_fun <- function (x, frequency_var) {
  df2 <- df %>% 
    dplyr::select(x, frequency_var) %>% 
    tidyr::uncount(frequency_var)   %>% 
    dplyr::arrange(x)
  df2
}

my_fun("a", "freq")
Error: `weights` must evaluate to a numeric vector
Called from: tidyr::uncount(., frequency_var)
```

My `freq` variable is numeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling it in a function I would suggest to have a look at non-standard evaluation. Using curly-curly (`{{}}`) operator from `rlang` we can pass unquoted variable names in the function. Also it is better to pass dataframe name in the function to get the correct context.

```
library(rlang)

my_fun <- function (df, x, frequency_var) {
   df2 <- df %>% 
            dplyr::select({{x}}, {{frequency_var}}) %>% 
            tidyr::uncount({{frequency_var}})   %>% 
            dplyr::arrange({{x}})
    df2
}

my_fun(df, a, freq)

#   a
#1  2
#2  2
#3  2
#4  3
#5  3
#6  3
#7  3
#8  4
#9  4
#10 4
#11 4
#12 4
```

Comment: I thought putting "" around the variables `my_fun("a", "freq")` would cover it. I'll just stick to curly-curly